# AppointmentManager.RequestStoreAsync throws system.unauthorizedaccessexception in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-7.1

I am trying to access the appointments from the Windows Phone calendar

```
public async Task <AppointmentStore> getAppointments()
    {

        AppointmentStore appointmentStore = await  AppointmentManager.RequestStoreAsync(AppointmentStoreAccessType.AllCalendarsReadOnly);
        return appointmentStore;

    }
```

I have already the "enabled" the "Appointments" in the Capabilities tab of PackageManifest file. In the other solutions on the stack overflow it was suggested to enable the required permission which I did. I have also ran the Visual Studio as an administrator. However, the system continues to throws the same unauthorized access exception.

Comment: Please uninstall the app from device. Do a solution rebuild/clean build and try again. Let me know if this fixes it, has happened to me. Of course make sure Capabilities are enabled.

Comment: I did uninstall the app, cleaned and rebuilt the solution. However, it still shows the same exception. I think it may have something to do with threading.

Comment: Can you please post the stack trace? Also, is it a WP8.1 Runtime app or WP8.1 silverlight app.

Comment: Never mind, I generated the error looking into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `AppointmentStoreAccessType.AppCalendarsReadWrite` no exceptions are thrown.

Using `AppointmentStoreAccessType.AllCalendarsReadOnly` throws unauthorized exception. Which is not harmful, doesn't make the app crash. This just means you don't have `ChangeTracker` property.

You can still use the `appointmentStore` object and get list of appointments and other things. Check screenshot.[image]

I hope you can proceed on your project now?